# How to use nested routes with several parameters in ember 2.17

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, frontend, ember-cli

I am trying to build an smarthome app and I am stuck with calling nested routes with serveral parameters. I want to show an information which user is logged in and below that template which is in my parent route i want to render child pages for showing households. After a specific household is chosen, i want to show the rooms in the household and then devices. This is my router.js

```
    Router.map(function() {
      this.route('about');
      this.route('users', function() {
      });
      this.route('households', { path: '/:user_id' }, function() {
        this.route('index', { path: '/:user_id' })
        this.route('rooms',{ path: '/:household_id' });
        this.route('devices', { path: '/:room_id' });
      });
    });

export default Router;
```

I link to households like this

```
  <h3>{{#link-to "households" user.id}}{{user.surname}}{{/link-to}}</h3>
```

and now I want to declare a model in the route of households.js which returns an user from the ember data store and render the parent template. Afterwards the model should redirect to households.index with the user.id too and the households.index.hbs should render all households below the parent template.
 My households.js route looks like this:

```
export default Route.extend({
  model(params){
    {
      return this.get('store').findRecord('user', params.user_id);
    }
  }
});
```

and my household.index route like this

```
export default Route.extend({
    model(params) {
       return this.get('store').findAll('household').then(results => results.filter((site) => {
           return site.get('member').filter(x => x == params.user_id).length > 0;
       }));
      }
});
```

Actually the following error occurs:

> Error: Assertion Failed: You
>   attempted to define a `{{link-to "households.rooms"}}` but did not
>   pass the parameters required for generating its dynamic segments. You
>   must provide param `user_id` to `generate`.

In general I need serveral parameters in all nested routes/subroutes, because I need the user_id for example in the route devices for checking if the calling user is a admin. If he is an admin he would be able to add and edit devices. And i need the room_id to show only devices which are in the chosen room.

Is there any way to pass serveral parameters or using the controllers in a way, I can handle my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, you haven't set up the routing hierarchy well.

**Assuming** that you have multiple users, and every user has multiple households, and every household has multiple rooms, I suggest you make your `router.js` like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('users', function() {
    this.route('index'); // Lists all the users, URL looks like /users
    this.route('single', { path: '/:user_id' }, function() {
      this.route('index'); // Shows a single user, URL looks like /users/123
      this.route('households', function() {
        this.route('index'); // Shows all households a user with user_id has, URL looks like /users/123/households
        this.route('single',{ path: '/:household_id' }, function() {
          this.route('index'); // Shows a single household, URL looks like /users/123/households/456
          this.route('rooms', function() {
            this.route('index'); // Shows all rooms a household with household_id has, URL looks like /users/123/households/456/rooms
            this.route('single', { path: '/:room_id' }); // Shows a single room, URL looks like /users/123/households/456/rooms/789
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Feel free to omit `this.route('index');` lines in the router if you want, but make sure you make a route to handle this. Your templates should look something like this.

```
// templates/users.hbs

{{outlet}}


// templates/users/index.hbs

<h1>This shows all the users</h1>

<ul>
{{#each model as |user|}}
  <li>{{user.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>


// templates/users/single.hbs

{{outlet}}


// templates/users/single/index.hbs

<h1>This shows a single user with id {{model.id}}</h1>

<p>This is the user named {{model.name}}.</p>


// templates/users/single/households.hbs

{{outlet}}


// ... And so on
```

You should implement `model()` hooks in such a way that they fetch only what you really need. For the lists, you fetch them in the index `route.js` of the type you want to display (i.e. the `model()` of `routes/users/index.js` for users), and for the single record **not** in the index, but in the single `route.js` (i.e. for a single household in the `model()` of `routes/users/single/households/single.js`) to make that model accessible to both the index route and the child routes.

So, with this configuration, your links should look something like this:

```
// All users
{{#link-to 'users'}}All users{{/link-to}}

// Single user
{{#link-to 'users.single' user.id}}{{user.name}}{{/link-to}}

// Households of a single user
{{#link-to 'users.single.households' user.id}}All households of {{user.name}}{{/link-to}}

// Specific household of a single user
{{#link-to 'users.single.households.single' user.id household.id}}Household {{household.name}} of {{user.name}}{{/link-to}}

// Rooms within a specific household
{{#link-to 'users.single.households.single.rooms' user.id household.id}}All rooms within household {{household.name}} of {{user.name}}{{/link-to}}
```

**Note**: Make sure to specify models and their relationships properly to make your life easier from the very beginning. So, *for the configuration assumed at the beginning of this answer*, you should make your models something like this:

```
// models/user.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),

    households: DS.hasMany('household')
});


// models/household.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),

    user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    rooms: DS.hasMany('room')
});


// models/room.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),

    household: DS.belongsTo('household')
});
```

If you organize your models like this, then Ember will let you link from a rooms page (route) to the user's page like this:

```
{{#link-to 'users.single' model.household.user}}Go to user{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to build your example but the link to the households of a single user is not working, because the user id is undefined. My starting page got the url http://localhost:4200/users/index and when i click on my link which is implemented like you explained " {{#link-to 'users.single.households' user.id}}{{user.surname}}{{/link-to}}" it redirects to http://localhost:4200/users/131000/households/index and the passed user_id is undefined in my model hook. Do you have any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: okay for now it redirects me to localhost:4200/users/131000/households as you said, but I still have an undefined param. How can I access the 131000 now?

Comment: You can access all the `params` inside the `model(params)` hook of any route. That means that in a child route of the user you can access `params.user_id`, and from there on you can make sure to make it accessible to your model. So if you access the route `localhost:4200/users/131000/households`, its `model()` hook will receive `params` which will contain `user_id`.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!